# How to Move data from HDInsight hive tables into SQL DW?

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-synapse

Are there anyways to import data from HDInsight hive tables into SQL Datawarehouse(SQLDW) ?

Currently, the primary storage for HDInsight is ADLS (Datalake Store) and ADLS holds whole set of raw data. I don't want to move my data into Storage account as ADLS is acting as a Datalake in my case.

Which options are the most viable options here -

1. ADF - does it really support reading data directly from Hive tables?
2. Polybase -  does it support ADLS instead of Storage account?

supported links - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-overview-load

thanks

Comment: ADF supports extract from HDFS as one of it's sources.  [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-hdfs-connector) mentions Hive and AVRO format.  What format are your tables in?

Comment: I am dealing with ORC format.

Comment: Have you tried creating an external file format for ORC files as per [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935026.aspx) and then and external table on that?

Comment: thanks. it's worked fine. My cluster was on Linux but your above links did the trick.

Comment: Great, please post an example of your working code and mark it as answer.  That will make this post really useful for other users having the same issue who arrive at this page.